# Block container access to internet but still have a port open for access

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

What I am trying is to create a container isolated otherwise but having a port open for access from outside. I'd like to keep it so that container can't access internet.

I have `internal` network and container that has a single port open for accessing the service.

example `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  vaultwarden:
    driver: default
    internal: true

services:
  vaultwarden:
    image: vaultwarden/server:latest
    container_name: vaultwarden
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8050:80
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /home/user/password_test:/data/
    environment:
      - WEBSOCKET_ENABLED=true
      - ROCKET_WORKERS=8
    networks:
      - vaultwarden
```

It seems to work, service is accessible in `localhost:8050` and from the container I can't access internet.

Still I am wondering is this right way to do it?

EDIT: I'm using `podman-compose` where this works but in `docker-compose` I have to put `bridge` instead of `default`. And it seems with docker this solution does not work at all

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I would like to mention an alternative. If vaultwarden supports [_socket activation_](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html), an alternative solution could be running a podman container   with `podman run --network=none ...`. That would prevent outgoing connections (see https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/13390). You would then also have the possibility to use a Unix socket with limited file permissions to prevent other local users from connecting to the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of some sorts was to create a reverse-proxy and attach it to to the `internal` and to a `driver:bridge` network. Now the traffic to vaultwarden app goes through the other network and vaultwarden itself can't access internet.

```
networks:
  vaultwarden_net_internal:
    internal: true
  vaultwarden_net_outside:
    driver: bridge

services:
  vaultwarden:
    image: vaultwarden/server:latest
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - /home/user/password_test:/data/
    environment:
      - WEBSOCKET_ENABLED=true
      - ROCKET_WORKERS=8
    networks:
      - vaultwarden_net_internal

  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
    - vaultwarden_net_internal
    - vaultwarden_net_outside
    ports:
      - 8051:80
    depends_on:
      - vaultwarden
```

Comment: But this does not work in podman... only docker :/